# Create environment variables from rows in data.frame/table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame like so

```
dt <- data.frame(
  x = c("a","b","c","d"),
  y = c(1,2,3,4)
)
```

How can I create environment variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` with the corresponding value in `dt$y`, using `dt`? A la:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
d <- 4
```

[open to `data.table`-specific answers as well]

Comment: You probably shouldn't. There may be another approach to avoid it

Comment: @d.b more like there is _often_ a better approach to avoid it

Answer (score 3):

you can use `list2env`

```
list2env(setNames(as.list(dt$y), dt$x), envir = .GlobalEnv )
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `assign`:

```
apply(dt, 1, function(x) assign(x[1], x[2], envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this though, since it is much better to work with a dataframe, than separate variables in your global environment. Use with caution.